# Why do I get a merge conflict?

Tags: git-merge

I just downloaded the most recent version of Git to my Windows platform.  I have a file with the following content committed:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

I then create a branch with: **git branch development**
I continue on the **master** branch and modify the first line so I now have:

```
Line 1master
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

I stage and commit the change on the **master** branch.  I switch to the **development** branch and modify the second line so I now have:

```
Line 1
Line 2development
Line 3
Line 4
```

I stage and commit the change on the **development** branch.  I now switch back to the **master** branch.  I attempt to merge the **development** branch with:
**git merge development**
I get the following conflict:

```
<<<<<<<< HEAD
Line 1master
Line 2
=======
Line 1
Line 2development
>>>>>>> development
Line 3
Line 4
```

But why? After the branch was created, a change was made each on the master and development branches.  But they were to different lines in the file.  So why a conflict?

Comment: The changes are too close together for Git to be sure that they are disjoint.

Comment: I tried it again with the changes in line 1 and 4 and there was no conflict.  I still don't quite buy that Git can't figure this out.  The MINIMAL change to the file done on the master branch since the development branch was created was just a one-line change.  Likewise on the development branch at the time of the merge and these were disjoint changes.  Why would Git not use minimal differences?

Comment: And what is the threshold Git uses and is it configurable?

Answer (score 0):

You get the conflict because **you made the development branch before commiting the changes on master**, so master has different content (line1master) at the moment you try to merge the development branch.

this image illustrates better the case;

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I think it does... that explains WHY the OP needs to merge... and the reason is clearly explained

Comment: The OP is asking why there's a conflict at all - the changes are not touching the same part of the file.

Comment: Nope.  Two developers should be able to modify different parts of the same file without conflict.  When I repeated the "experiment" modifying Line 1 in one branch and Line 4 in another branch, there was no conflict.  The difference was that the two lines modified were not next to one another.  So what?